# Springboot asynchronous

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

Could you please review this code and let me know if it's asynchronous or synchronous? If it's synchronous, can you suggest how to make it asynchronous for both the post and get controllers? Thank you.

i'm expect a positive response on my question

reactive controller

```
package com.example.reactive;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
public class ReactiveController {

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveRepository repo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/superhero", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Superhero> getSuperHero() {

        
        return repo.findAll().delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(3));

    }

    @PostMapping("/superhero")
    public Mono<Superhero> addSuperHero(@RequestBody Superhero hero) {

        return repo.save(hero);

    }
}
```

//ReactiveRepository

```
package com.example.reactive;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository;

public interface ReactiveRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Superhero, String> {

}
```

// reactive spring java application

```
package com.example.reactive;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ReactivespringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReactivespringApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

//model

```
package com.example.reactive;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Document
@Data
@Builder
public class Superhero {

    
    @Id
    private String id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private int age;
}
```

Comment: It is written in documentation. Try to answer it yourself. If I answer it, you won't figure it out yourself next time.

Comment: please help me i'm fresher and new to this technology...

Comment: It's asynchronous and reactive

Comment: can you confirm this one 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76184221/is-my-spring-boot-rest-api-implementation-non-blocking-and-how-can-i-confirm-it

Comment: stack overflow is not a code reviewing service there is a separate site for that https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry I didn't know about that thing

Comment: Before posting on Code Review please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)